# How to find a resource string in Android by a string value?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I in my strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="a">A value</string>
    <string name="b">Another value</string>
</resources>
```

And I'd like to get "A value" or "Another value" from a String value. At runtime it could be "a" or "b", but I have no control over it.

So let's say, at some point, String myString = "a". How can I put "A value" in a String local variable?

Comment: `String yourString = getResources().getString(R.string.a);`

Comment: The downvotes do not seem justified. Many do not seem to properly understand the question as reflected in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use switch-case:

```
private String getValue(String valueOf) {
    int resourceVal = 0;
    switch(valueOf) {
        case "a":
            resourceVal = R.string.a;
            break;
        case "b":
            resourceVal = R.string.b;
            break;
    }
    if (resourceVal != 0) {
        return getResources().getString(resourceVal);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I think i will stay with your solution. I thought the Android framework has a special method for this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity type `R.string.` and press `alt+enter`
it will show you the available strings.

```
 R.string.a
 R.string.b
```

Please write back to tell me if it helped. If it did please mark as answered and upvote ;)

also refer to the documentation see link below

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: But the problem I have, is I don't know which one I need. I fetch a data from a web service and I get an ID along many other data. And with this given String value, the ID, I have to get the right string from this strings.xml. Sometimes it could be "a", another time "b" or many other values.

Comment: well it's a logic problem but i you know what could possibly the return of the api then you can set a flag something like this

``` if(id == 1){
         R.string.a
    }

Comment: Yes, if you know the IDs you can use this kind of logic `switch(id){ case 1: someString = getResources().getString(R.string.a); break; case 2:someString = getResources().getString(R.string.b); break;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = getString(R.string.yourStringName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a logic problem but if you know what could possibly the return of the api then you can set a flag something like this

`if(id == 1 )
{
     R.string.a
}`

Comment: Yes this it would do the trick, but i wondered if there's any elegant and easy solution instead of the good old if-else if statements.

Comment: if it is a chunk of code  create class  or  just use switch-case